# How to set size of panel in c# as float/double data type?

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a C# form and added a panel. I want to set panel size to height=250.75 and width to 475.25. How to do so. I tried it but it shows error message "Property value not valid.  250.5 is not a valid value for Int32."

Comment: panel sizes can only be set to an integer, not a double/float

Comment: You are asking how to fit a square peg in a round hole.  The answer is you can't.

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory, so there is no real question here.

Comment: @user8353837 you're getting a lot of negative feedback because your question has no code shown, and no really effort put into it. Try reviewing https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for future questions

Comment: Thanks for opinion but is there any alternative way to do so because i want to control the size of the panel from textboxes. When i enter value to the textboxes then it should change the size of panel according to the entered value. And it will deal with cm, mm, inch from comboBox. Conversion among cm, mm, inch to pixel will deal with float or double. That's the reason i was asking for it. So, any suggestions?

Comment: "You can't do it" is not an opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is short and sad: you can't do it.

Comment: Such a sad answer.

Comment: Actually that's quite a happy answer. It's much easier to work with whole numbers